# VS 2017 specified deps.json does not exist asp.net core application

Tags: javascript, c#, php, asp.net, .net

I have a database I am trying to scaffold and my question is nearly identical to question in the specified deps.json does not exist angular2 asp.net core application. However mine is using VS 2017 and it's a regular MVC project - not Angular.

There is no project.json in VS2017 as most of the functionality is now in cs.proj. Do I need to make a change of some sort in cs.proj or is there some other approach to this error? At this point it's a fresh project (started in VS 2017) and I'm following the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db - except I'm using my own database.

Comment: VS 2017 does not make use of json config's anymore. It is integrated into the .csproj file now. What you can do is if you need to change something specfic to the .net core project you can edit the csproj and reload when done. Or if you want to have custom configurations or settings you can create an appsettings.json file and extract it via the ms's configuration manager.